# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

i have deployes ReactJS application on github pages but getting there errors.
[image: error getting]

Although all the API's are working fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that adblock recognizes the word advertisement in the URL and it thinks it's an ad.
Many applications work this way (for example it happened to me that Kaspersky blocked a page on a site i own because it contained the words toss and ban) so you should be careful about the URL you write to take into account that visitors might have applications that block certain bad words.

Comment: how to resolve it? i have disabled all the extensions.